# Override id on a ruby object (created using OpenStruct)

Tags: ruby, object

I want to convert a hash to an object using [OpenStruct](http://www.ensta.fr/~diam/ruby/online/ruby-doc-stdlib/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/classes/OpenStruct.html) that has an `id` property, however the resultant `object#id` returns the native object id, e.g.

```
test = OpenStruct.new({:id => 666})
test.id # => 70262018230400
```

Is there anyway to override this? As at the moment my workaround isn't so pretty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`OpenStruct` uses a combination of `define_method` calls inside an `unless self.respond_to?(name)` check and `method_missing`. This means if the property name conflicts with the name of any existing method on the object then you will encounter this problem.

[tokland's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188031/tokland) answer if good but another alternative is to undefine the `id` method e.g.

```
test.instance_eval('undef id')
```

You could also incorporate this into your own customised version of `OpenStruct` e.g.

```
class OpenStruct2 < OpenStruct
  undef id
end

irb(main):009:0> test2 = OpenStruct2.new({:id => 666})
=> #<OpenStruct2 id=666>
irb(main):010:0> test2.id
=> 666
```

Comment: It sounds good, you don't depend on any instance variable (@table, which may be refactored).

Answer (score 1):

This was the classical workaround, I'd be also glad to hear a better way:

```
>> OpenStruct.send(:define_method, :id) { @table[:id] }
=> #<Proc:0x00007fbd43798990@(irb):1>
>> OpenStruct.new(:id => 666).id
=> 666
```

Answer (score 0):

I've switched to using [Hashery](http://rubyworks.github.com/hashery/) and the BasicStruct (renamed version of [OpenObject](http://rubyworks.github.com/hashery/docs/api/OpenObject.html) in latest version, 1.4) as that allows me to do this:

```
x = BasicStruct.new({:id => 666, :sub => BasicStruct.new({:foo => 'bar', :id => 777})})
x.id       # => 666
x.sub.id   # => 777
x.sub.foo  # => "bar"
```